# Merging raster files produces error in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, merge

I'm trying to merge (Raster -> Miscellanous -> Merge) four raster files into one. Each file has same CRS and are saved as .tif files. Merge produces error:

"The process crashed some time after starting successfully."

The layers themselves don't overlap.

Comment: I can't answer your question. However, i can refer you to an online tool. https://www.coolutils.com/Online/TIFF-Combine/

Comment: Have you tried building a **virtual raster**? (_Raster > Miscellanous > Build Virtual Raster_)

Comment: Making a virtual raster works out fine, but saving the output as a raster file (.tiff) messes up again. Saved file is completely distorted and black & white.

Comment: Ah, it just messed up the style nicely. Now it works well!

So the original problem was solved just by building a virtual raster and then saving the output as a raster (.gtiff).

Answer (score 1):

I have known this happen due to there being lots of files to merge and the folder and file tree names are long. Resolve by shortening the folder files names.

I have it happen for other currently unknown reasons too!

Answer (score 1):

This also happended to me. I don't know why, but when activating "grab pseudocolor table from first image", the process doesn't crash.
However, I'd recommend to try the SAGA tool "mosaic raster layers" as it gives you much more control (e.g. when troubleshooting edge effects)